# Find the value of the defined key of a dict within a list, by matching the dict values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Input is simple csv file with header what looks like:

```
dc,environment,type,component,fqdn,distribution,release
1,prod,web,fo,aa,ubuntu,14.04.5
```

It is loaded by `csv.DictReader(csv)` into the `server_list`:

```
def get_server(**kwargs):
    f = open("servers.dat", 'rt')
    try:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        server_list = []
        for row in reader:
            server_list.append(row)
    finally:
        f.close()
```

List contains:

```
{'component': 'a', 'dc': '1', 'fqdn': 'aa', 'environment': 'prod', 'release': '14.04.5', 'distribution': 'ubuntu', 'type': 'web'}
{'component': 'a', 'dc': '1', 'fqdn': 'bb', 'environment': 'prod', 'release': '14.04.5', 'distribution': 'ubuntu', 'type': 'web'}
{'component': 'b', 'dc': '1', 'fqdn': 'cc', 'environment': 'prod', 'release': '12.04.5', 'distribution': 'ubuntu', 'type': 'web'}
{'component': 'a', 'dc': '1', 'fqdn': 'dd', 'environment': 'test02', 'release': '14.04.5', 'distribution': 'ubuntu', 'type': 'web'}
```

I would like to get value of `fqdn` when input will be e.g. `dc = 1 and component = a` from python function called e.g. `get_foo(dc='1', component='a', environment=None)` and `defined def get_foo(**kwargs)` or differently. Only result is required.

So, expected result in this case are all these lines except 3rd.

Thank you

Comment: Is this a file content? This is not a valid data structure. Also include what have you tried.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get help, you need to show 1) What your input looks like, 2) What the expected output looks like, 3) Your requirements, and most important of all: 4) What have you tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are right. Question updated. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally

```
def get_foo(l, **kwargs):
    return [x['fqdn'] for x in l if all(x[i] == kwargs[i] for i in kwargs)]
```

This will throw a `KeyError` exception is you pass a keyword argument not in the dictionary `x`

Comment: Hi @PatrickHaugh many thanks. It works as expected. Thats very elegant solution. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that you have a list of `dict`s, something like this:

```
>>> a = [{'component': 'a',
          'dc': '1',
          'distribution': 'ubuntu',
          'environment': 'prod',
          'fqdn': 'aa',
          'release': '14.04.5',
          'type': 'web'},
         {'component': 'a',
          'dc': '1',
          'distribution': 'ubuntu',
          'environment': 'prod',
          'fqdn': 'bb',
          'release': '14.04.5',
          'type': 'web'},
         {'component': 'b',
          'dc': '1',
          'distribution': 'ubuntu',
          'environment': 'prod',
          'fqdn': 'cc',
          'release': '12.04.5',
          'type': 'web'},
         {'component': 'a',
          'dc': '1',
          'distribution': 'ubuntu',
          'environment': 'test02',
          'fqdn': 'dd',
          'release': '14.04.5',
          'type': 'web'}]
```

You can always just filter the list of `dict`s using [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) syntax:

```
>>> [x['fqdn'] for x in a if x['dc'] == '1' and x['component'] == 'a']
['aa', 'bb', 'dd']
```

To wrap it up in a function:

```
def get_foo(dlist, dc='1', component='a'):
    return [dv['fqdn'] for dv in dlist
            if dv['dc'] == dc
            and dv['component'] == component]
```

And then:

```
>>> get_foo(a)
['aa', 'bb', 'dd']
```

Comment: I'm looking for solution when number of conditions depends on arguments. What if I need to compare 3 keys and not 2 and their values, or 4 etc. I do not want to edit if statement. It should be "dynamic".

Comment: The answer by @PatrickHaugh is what you're looking for, I think.  `all` over a generator expression of Boolean values is like `and`ing together a whole bunch of conditions.